# anchoring a geomety/mesh to it's corner for scaling three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm create a rectangle in three.js based on 2 coordinates. The first coordinate is the cell of the first user click, the second coordinate is where the user drags the cursor.

The rectanlge that is being created is the correct size, however it 'grows' from it's center, whereas I want it to 'grow' from the corner of the first user click. I've tried a few potential solutions to change the origin of the geometry but I haven't found a fix yet.

[The demo can be see here](http://3dblueprint.uk/test/) - with the code below.

```
    var startPoint = startPlace;
    var endPoint = endPlace;
    var zIntersect = new THREE.Vector3(startPoint.x, 0, endPoint.z);
    var xIntersect = new THREE.Vector3(endPoint.x, 0, startPoint.z);

    var differenceZ = Math.abs(startPlace.z - zIntersect.z);
    var differenceX = Math.abs(startPlace.x - xIntersect.x);
    floorGeometryNew.rotateX(-Math.PI / 2);


    var floorGeometryNew = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(differenceX, differenceZ);
    floorGeometryNew.rotateX(-Math.PI / 2);

    var x = startPoint.x;
    var y = startPoint.y;
    var z = startPoint.z;

    var voxel = new THREE.Mesh(floorGeometryNew, tempMaterial);
    voxel.position.set(x, y, z);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Center of your rectangle is in the middle between `startPoint` and `endPoint` and it's the average of them:

```
voxel.position.addVectors(startPoint, endPoint).divideScalar(2);
```

**Approach 1.** Without creating of a new geometry every time when you change size of a rectangle. The idea is:

1. Create a mesh of a plane once on start with a double-sided material
2. Set the first vertex of the plane's geometry with the current point of intersection
3. Track the point of intersection and apply its value to the last vertex of the plane's geometry and change the second and the third vertices accordingly to positions of the first and the last vertices

For example, we created a plane mesh `newRect` on `mouseDown` event and set its geometry's first vertex to the point of intersection which was on that moment:

```
newRectGeom.vertices[0].set(onPlanePoint.x, onPlanePoint.y + .5, onPlanePoint.z);
```

and then on `mouseMove` we get the point of intersection and apply its coordinate to the fourth (last) vertex, also we change values of vertices 1 and 2:

```
newRect.geometry.vertices[1].set(onPlanePoint.x, newRect.geometry.vertices[0].y, newRect.geometry.vertices[0].z);
newRect.geometry.vertices[2].set(newRect.geometry.vertices[0].x, newRect.geometry.vertices[0].y, onPlanePoint.z);
newRect.geometry.vertices[3].set(onPlanePoint.x, onPlanePoint.y + .5, onPlanePoint.z);
```

It's simplier than it sounds :)

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/x7gvvywo/) example. Build mode off - OrbitControls are enabled; Build mode on - controls are disabled, you can draw rectangles.

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000000);
camera.position.set(0, 10, 20);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(0x999999);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

var planeGeo = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(20, 20);
planeGeo.rotateX(-Math.PI / 2);
var plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeo, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: "darkgray"
}));
scene.add(plane);

var grid = new THREE.GridHelper(20, 40);
grid.position.set(0, .05, 0);
scene.add(grid);


var buildMode = true;
buildMe.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (buildMode) {
    indicator.innerHTML = "off";
  } else {
    indicator.innerHTML = "on";
  }
  buildMode = !buildMode;
  controls.enabled = !buildMode;
}, false);

var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(),
  mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
document.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUp, false);
document.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown, false);
document.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMove, false);

var newRect;
var buildStarted = false;
var onPlanePoint;
var intersect;

function mouseUp(event) {
  console.log("mouseup fired");
  buildStarted = false;
  newRect = undefined;
}

function mouseDown(event) {
  if (buildMode && onPlanePoint) {
    console.log("mousedown fired");
    buildStarted = true;
    var newRectGeom = new THREE.PlaneGeometry();
    console.log(newRectGeom);
    newRectGeom.vertices[0].set(onPlanePoint.x, onPlanePoint.y + .5, onPlanePoint.z);
    var newRectMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      side: THREE.DoubleSide,
      color: Math.random() * 0xffffff,
      transparent: true,
      opacity: 0.25
    })
    newRect = new THREE.Mesh(newRectGeom, newRectMaterial);
    scene.add(newRect);
  }
}

function mouseMove(event) {
  mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
  intersect = raycaster.intersectObjects([plane]);
  if (intersect.length) {
    onPlanePoint = intersect[0].point;
  } else {
    onPlanePoint = undefined;
  }
}
render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  if (newRect) {
    if (buildStarted) {
      newRect.geometry.vertices[1].set(onPlanePoint.x, newRect.geometry.vertices[0].y, newRect.geometry.vertices[0].z);
      newRect.geometry.vertices[2].set(newRect.geometry.vertices[0].x, newRect.geometry.vertices[0].y, onPlanePoint.z);
      newRect.geometry.vertices[3].set(onPlanePoint.x, onPlanePoint.y + .5, onPlanePoint.z);
      newRect.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
    }

  }
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

#buildMe {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.122.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.122.0/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.min.js"></script>

<button id="buildMe">
  Build Mode: <span id="indicator">off</span>
</button>
```

**Approach 2.** Instead of controlling vertices we can control position and scaling of rectangle.

On `mousedown` event we'll set the `startPoint` with the point of intersection

```
startPoint.copy(onPlanePoint);
```

and then we'll find position and scaling of our rectangle:

```
newRect.position.addVectors(startPoint, onPlanePoint).divideScalar(2);
newRect.position.y = 0.5; // to avoid z-fight
newRect.scale.set(Math.abs(onPlanePoint.x - startPoint.x), 1, Math.abs(onPlanePoint.z - startPoint.z))
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/0pemrnjt/) example. Visually and functionally it's the same as the `Approach 1`. From my point of view, `Approach 2` is simplier.

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000000);
camera.position.set(0, 10, 20);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(0x999999);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

var planeGeo = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(20, 20);
planeGeo.rotateX(-Math.PI / 2);
var plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeo, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: "darkgray"
}));
scene.add(plane);

var grid = new THREE.GridHelper(20, 40);
grid.position.set(0, .05, 0);
scene.add(grid);


var buildMode = false;
buildMe.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (buildMode) {
    indicator.innerHTML = "off";
  } else {
    indicator.innerHTML = "on";
  }
  buildMode = !buildMode;
  controls.enabled = !buildMode;
}, false);

var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(),
  mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
document.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUp, false);
document.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown, false);
document.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMove, false);

var newRect;
var buildStarted = false;
var onPlanePoint;
var startPoint = new THREE.Vector3();
var intersect;

function mouseUp(event) {
  console.log("mouseup fired");
  buildStarted = false;
  newRect = undefined;
}

function mouseDown(event) {
  if (buildMode && onPlanePoint) {
    buildStarted = true;
    var newRectGeom = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1, 1);
    newRectGeom.rotateX(-Math.PI / 2);
    var newRectMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      color: Math.random() * 0xffffff,
      transparent: true,
      opacity: 0.25
    })
    newRect = new THREE.Mesh(newRectGeom, newRectMaterial);
    startPoint.copy(onPlanePoint);
    scene.add(newRect);
  }
}

function mouseMove(event) {
  mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
  intersect = raycaster.intersectObjects([plane]);
  if (intersect.length) {
    onPlanePoint = intersect[0].point;
  } else {
    onPlanePoint = undefined;
  }
}
render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  if (newRect) {
    if (buildStarted) {
      newRect.position.addVectors(startPoint, onPlanePoint).divideScalar(2);
      newRect.position.y = 0.5;
      newRect.scale.set(Math.abs(onPlanePoint.x - startPoint.x), 1, Math.abs(onPlanePoint.z - startPoint.z))
    }

  }
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

#buildMe {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.122.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.122.0/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.min.js"></script>

<button id="buildMe">
  Build Mode: <span id="indicator">off</span>
</button>
```

[image]

Comment: how to do this when I want the rectangle to be rotated and inclined. For Example I would like to draw a rectangle on a titled roof of a building and the building rotated by 30 degrees

Answer (score 0):

When you call

```
voxel.position.set(x, y, z);
```

then the center of your mesh is setted to this position. So you have to take half of the length and half of the width of your rectangle to add to this position. These values you can get with a bounding box.

```
var bbox = new THREE.Box3();
bbox.setFromObject( voxel );
var val = bbox.max.x - bbox.min.x;
```